# Magento 2: My popup modal is not showing on all pages, it's only showing on home page

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.4, modal-popup

### **It's only on the homepage**

[image]

### When I go to another page it doesn't show anything and gives an error

[image]

### Here are my files

[image]

### Here is my modal_popup.js file:

[image]

### And here is my requirejs-config.js file :

[image]

### I put it in magento_Cms, this is the path where I put www/html/magento245/app/design/frontend/themeCustom/ firefox/Magento_Cms

### I'm new to magento 2, please help me to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you declare your `phtml` file in `<your theme dir>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml`, so your `phtml` file (which contains `popup` HTML div) is only available on the homepage.

In order to add your `phtml` file to all pages, you should declare it in `default.xml` in your module or your theme:

- `<your theme dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`
- `<your module dir>/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

Comment: thanks it's work !!

Comment: You're welcome!